# TypeError: mapLayers[i].getSource is not a function

Tags: javascript

Now I build an openlayer map with ol-layerswitcher (walkermatt). The map is working in other version with OL 6 and Firefox. https://www.kweimar.de/TB_MapOS.html (There is the link from the sidebar (onClick) only with firefox working.)
In the https://www.kweimar.de/TB_MapOS1.html is the error
Uncaught TypeError: mapLayers[i].getSource is not a function
Because the function is working in the other version, I think there is another problem.
With the key is the map only working at my account. This is the part:

```
var select = new ol.interaction.Select();
map.addInteraction(select);
var selectedFeatures = select.getFeatures();
var infoBox = document.getElementById('sidebar-list');

map.on('moveend', function(e) {
infoBox.innerHTML = "";
var info = [];
var mapLayers = map.getLayers().getArray();
for(var i=1;i<7 ; i++) {
    if (mapLayers[i].getVisible()==true) {
        var Source = mapLayers[i].getSource();
        var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
        Source.forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent(extent, function(feature) {
            nam = feature.get('name')
            nummer = feature.get('nummer');
            listed = feature.get('listed');
//          searchString="Llan";
            if(nam !== null && nam.toUpperCase().match(searchString.toUpperCase())){
            info.push([nam,listed,nummer]);
            }
        });         
    }   // ende if
}   // ende for
```

Thank you